# How to model dependencies between components in a lower level view

Tags: dependencies, uml, component-diagram

I have a component diagram (level 1) with dependencies between the internal components. The Account component "uses" the Billing component:

[image]

Now I want to create a level 2 diagram of the Account component. How do I model the "usage" dependency between Account and Billing (now outside of the view)? Should I create a port? Is it ok to omit it completely?

[image]

Comment: Depends on what to show. You can just repeat the representation of the first diagram with no extra details. Or you show ports if you need it. Your question is unclear reagrding your goals.

Comment: For me the question is what the readers expect and if they would miss these dependencies.

Comment: Well, you must know your readership. We don't....

Answer (score 1):

From the UML standard, all three options are allowed:

1. Omit `Billing` completely.
2. Show `Billing` outside of `Account` and have a «use» relationship directly from one of the inner components to `Billing`.
3. Show `Billing` outside of `Account` and connect it via a port and an interface.

Which option you choose is highly subjective.

Here are some considerations:

1. Use option 1 if the connection with `Billing` is not something you want to convey to the reader in this diagram.
2. Use option 2 if the name of the interface via which the connection with `Billing` is made is too much detail to show in this diagram.
3. Use option 3 otherwise.